# Is it possible to make ABC from these rules?

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic

Okay so we were asked this question the other day. I've given it a decent chunk of my life already and like any reasonable confused person, I have naturally turned to the internet for help.

The game is as follows: Make a string of 'ABC' using only the rules below. Only use one rule at a time. A rule can be used more than once. (It was hinted that the answer had fewer steps than $11$, but not confirmed).

> - Rule $0$: You must start with the string D.
> - Rule $1$: If you have a string whose last letter is D, then you can add a B on the end.
> - Rule $2$: If you have a string which is of the form A(s) where (s) is any string, then you can make A(s)(s). (To clarify, (s) is a string that is comprised of all remaining characters after the initial A, for example, A$123$ would become A$123123$.)
> - Rule $3$: If you have a string which contains DDD, you can replace the DDD with B.
> - Rule $4$: If you have a string which contains BB, you can delete the BB from the string.
> - Rule $5$: If you have a string which does not end with A, then you can insert an A at the front.
> - Rule $6$: If you have a string which is exactly four letters long, you may add an A to the end.
> - Rule $7$: If you have a string which contains an equal number of each letter A, B, and D, you may do nothing (pass).
> - Rule $8$: If you have a string which contains AA, you may replace the AA with DDD.
> - Rule $9$: If you have the string AB, you can add C to the end, and have finished.

I've already given this problem a great deal of thought and have gone so far as to [write a program](http://pastebin.com/1RQZLfV8) to calculate [all valid steps](http://download936.mediafire.com/nboltd9a8sug/1d5c7lipo6bae41/results.txt) one could take, but alas that hasn't yet yielded an answer.

The only way to achieve the final result of ABC is to remove all instances of D, which is accomplishable through doubling the string (rule $2$) or by adding three D's to the string (rules $5,5,8$), then replace all instances of D with B (rule $3$) and delete the B's from the string (rule $5$). However, the number of D's must be divisible by three.

So I guess in this long-winded way I'm simply asking this: is it even possible to make ABC from these rules, given ANY number of steps, let alone fewer than $11$? (It's starting to get to my head, we're being taunted by being told that this problem is 'as easy as ABC'.)

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if the number of Ds in a string is not a multiple of 3 before a rule is applied, then it's also not a multiple of 3 after the rule is applied (seen just by examining each rule separately). Therefore there's no way to start with "D" and end up in a string whose number of Ds is a multiple of 3; in particular, it's impossible to get rid of all the Ds in any way, much less end up with "ABC" specifically.